# Passing values from a child panel to a parent panel

Tags: java, swing

I am having trouble trying to pass a value from a child to parent panel and was hoping to get some insight. my main panel holds a tabbed panel that holds a panel with two JCheckbox buttons. I am trying to pass the value I assigned to the check boxes to the tabbed panel where I can do addition to add a few more totals, then pass the new value from the tabbed panel to the main panel.

This is my main panel.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MasterPanel extends JPanel 
{   
    private JTabbedPane tp; 

    public MasterPanel () 
    {
        setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        // CENTER - displays the tabs with selections for the order
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        tp = new JTabbedPane();
        tp.addTab("Pizza", new PizzaOptionsPanel());
        add (tp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        // LINE_END (right) - displays running total for order
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------    
        add(new OrderSummaryPanel(),BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }

    public void update()
    {
        OrderSummaryPanel.update("Pizza Subtotal: " + PizzaOptionsPanel.getValue());
    }

}
```

The middle panel where I want to add multiple values and send the total to the main panel.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PizzaOptionsPanel extends JPanel {

    private JPanel size, crust, sauce, toppings;
    private int pizzaSubTotal, value;

    public PizzaOptionsPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout (1, 4));
        size = new PizzaSizePanel();
        add(size);
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and my inner pannel that I am trying to pass the value from the check box to the parent.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PizzaSizePanel extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel label;
    private JCheckBox size1, size2, size3, size4;
    private int sizeTotal;
    private PizzaOptionsPanel parent;

    public PizzaSizePanel() 
    {
        sizeTotal = 0;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        //creates size options
        label = new JLabel ("Pizza Size:");
        label.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 18));
        size1 = new MyJCheckBox ("10 inch:  $9", false, 9);
        size2 = new MyJCheckBox ("12 inch:  $11", false, 11);

        ButtonGroup SizeGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        SizeGroup.add (size1);
        SizeGroup.add (size2);

        add(label);
        add(size1);
        add(size2);

        size1.addActionListener(new PizzaListener());
        size2.addActionListener(new PizzaListener());
    }

    private class MyJCheckBox extends JCheckBox
    {
        private int value;
        public MyJCheckBox(String text, boolean checked, int newValue)
        {
            super(text, checked);
            value = newValue;
        }

        public int getValue()
        {
        return value;
        }
    }

    private class PizzaListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            MyJCheckBox temp = (MyJCheckBox)ae.getSource();
            boolean selected = (temp).isSelected();
            int val = temp.getValue();

            if(temp == size1)
                sizeTotal = val;
            else if(temp == size2)
                sizeTotal = val;
        }
    }

}
```

I believe this is an issue of inheritance correct?

I tried using a few getValue methods and maybe that was the correct way to try but it is possible I was doing that wrong?

Comment: *"I believe this is an issue of inheritance correct?"*, I'd argue it's an issue with design.  A lot of what you seem to be trying to do could be simply solved through a shared model, which is passed down from the parent to the children, the child components would then interact with the model as required. The model could implement an observer pattern to generate notifications about changes to itself, which other parties might be interested, allowing them to make changes in themselves.  This is a common enough problem, asked often enough, with plenty of repeated examples

Comment: You are interconnecting the ui parts with your real business model. Simply don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you want to do is define some kind of model which represents the data you're trying to capture/manage.

```
public interface PizzaOrder {
    public int getSize();
    public int getCrust();
    public int getSauce();
    public String[] getToppings();

    public void setSize(int size);
    public void setCrust(int crust);
    public void setSauce(int sauce);
    public void addTopping(String topping);
    public void removeTopping(String topping);

    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);
    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);
}
```

To my mind, this should also include a "tally" method which can calculate the tally of the options, this allows it to become self contained.  The question would be though, how would you feed the price information in? Well, surprising, this would be coupled with another model, which managed the items and their costs/multipliers based on the business rules.

This would mean that the price information is separated from the order information, but can be used by it to perform it's job, further decoupling the state.

You then make a implementation of the model

```
public class DefaultPizzaOrder implements PizzaOrder {

    private List<ChangeListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>(5);

    private int size;
    private int crust;
    private int sauce;
    private List<String> toppings = new ArrayList<>(25);

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCrust() {
        return crust;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSauce() {
        return sauce;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getToppings() {
        return toppings.toArray(new String[toppings.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        fireStateChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void setCrust(int crust) {
        this.crust = crust;
        fireStateChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSauce(int sauce) {
        this.sauce = sauce;
        fireStateChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void addTopping(String topping) {
        toppings.add(topping);
        fireStateChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTopping(String topping) {
        toppings.remove(topping);
        fireStateChanged();
    }

    protected void fireStateChanged() {
        ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(this);
        for (ChangeListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.stateChanged(evt);
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty basic, but the general idea is there.

Then, in your code, you create an instance of the model and pass it down to all the components which need it.  The components then interact with the model, updating it (or drawing information from) as required and triggering appropriate events which interested parties might be interested in

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MasterPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MasterPanel extends JPanel {

        private JTabbedPane tp;

        private PizzaOrder order;

        public MasterPanel() {
            order = new DefaultPizzaOrder();
            order.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    update();
                }
            });
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            // CENTER - displays the tabs with selections for the order
            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            tp = new JTabbedPane();
            tp.addTab("Pizza", new PizzaOptionsPanel(order));
            add(tp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            //-----------------------------------------------------------------
            // LINE_END (right) - displays running total for order
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------    
            add(new OrderSummaryPanel(), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        }

        public void update() {
            OrderSummaryPanel.update("Pizza Subtotal: " + PizzaOptionsPanel.getValue());
        }

    }

    public interface PizzaOrder {
        public int getSize();
        public int getCrust();
        public int getSauce();
        public String[] getToppings();

        public void setSize(int size);
        public void setCrust(int crust);
        public void setSauce(int sauce);
        public void addTopping(String topping);
        public void removeTopping(String topping);

        public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);
        public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);
    }

    public class DefaultPizzaOrder implements PizzaOrder {

        private List<ChangeListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>(5);

        private int size;
        private int crust;
        private int sauce;
        private List<String> toppings = new ArrayList<>(25);

        @Override
        public int getSize() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCrust() {
            return crust;
        }

        @Override
        public int getSauce() {
            return sauce;
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getToppings() {
            return toppings.toArray(new String[toppings.size()]);
        }

        @Override
        public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
            listeners.add(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
            listeners.remove(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void setSize(int size) {
            this.size = size;
            fireStateChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void setCrust(int crust) {
            this.crust = crust;
            fireStateChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void setSauce(int sauce) {
            this.sauce = sauce;
            fireStateChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void addTopping(String topping) {
            toppings.add(topping);
            fireStateChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeTopping(String topping) {
            toppings.remove(topping);
            fireStateChanged();
        }

        protected void fireStateChanged() {
            ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(this);
            for (ChangeListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.stateChanged(evt);
            }
        }
    }

    public class PizzaOptionsPanel extends JPanel {

        private JPanel size, crust, sauce, toppings;
        private int pizzaSubTotal, value;

        private PizzaOrder order;

        public PizzaOptionsPanel(PizzaOrder order) {
            this.order = order;
            setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
            size = new PizzaSizePanel(order);
            add(size);
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public class PizzaSizePanel extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;
        private JCheckBox size1, size2, size3, size4;
        private int sizeTotal;
        private PizzaOptionsPanel parent;
        private PizzaOrder order;

        public PizzaSizePanel(PizzaOrder order) {
            this.order = order;
            sizeTotal = 0;
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            //creates size options
            label = new JLabel("Pizza Size:");
            label.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 18));
            size1 = new MyJCheckBox("10 inch:  $9", false, 9);
            size2 = new MyJCheckBox("12 inch:  $11", false, 11);

            ButtonGroup SizeGroup = new ButtonGroup();
            SizeGroup.add(size1);
            SizeGroup.add(size2);

            add(label);
            add(size1);
            add(size2);

            size1.addActionListener(new PizzaListener());
            size2.addActionListener(new PizzaListener());
        }

        private class MyJCheckBox extends JCheckBox {

            private int value;

            public MyJCheckBox(String text, boolean checked, int newValue) {
                super(text, checked);
                value = newValue;
            }

            public int getValue() {
                return value;
            }
        }

        private class PizzaListener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                MyJCheckBox temp = (MyJCheckBox) ae.getSource();
                boolean selected = (temp).isSelected();
                int val = temp.getValue();

                order.setSize(val);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is reasonable simple example of a model/view paradigm, with an observer pattern